# Method for Object does not exist?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, twig, entity

I am new to symfony2 I'm trying to create a search function and got this

> error 'Method "ediTransaction" for object "Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\Edi997SegmentInError" does not exist in MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:rejectedTrans.html.twig at line 58'

is it what problem is it? Anyone?

Repository

```
class Edi997DetailsRepository extends EntityRepository{
    public function getDetails($gsNumber, $senderId, $receiverId, $page = 1, $limit = 5 ){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(

        'SELECT  partial a.{id, ak301, ak401},
         partial b.{errorCode, condition},
         partial c.{edi997DetailId, errorCodeId, noOfTrans},
         partial d.{ediTransactionId, senderId, receiverId, gsNumber, isaNumber, fileName}
        FROM MatrixEdiBundle:Edi997SegmentInError a
        JOIN a.ediAk403ErrorCodes b
        JOIN a.edi997Details c
        JOIN c.ediTransaction d
        WHERE d.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber
        AND d.senderId LIKE :senderId
        AND d.receiverId LIKE :receiverId
        AND c.errorCodeId != 1
        AND d.flag = 1')
        ->setParameter('gsNumber', "%$gsNumber%")
        ->setParameter('senderId', "%$senderId%")
        ->setParameter('receiverId', "%$receiverId%")
        ->setFirstResult(($page-1)*$limit)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);

        $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );

        $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);

    return $paginator;
   }
}
```

Twig :

```
{% if transaction != null %}
                        {% for trans in transaction %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 11%;">
                                  {{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getTradingPartnerName', {'timexID' : trans.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'customerID' : trans.ediTransaction.senderId})) }}
                                </td>

                                {% 
                                   set result=render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getFile', {'fileName' : trans.ediTransaction.fileName, 'senderId': trans.ediTransaction.receiverId , 'receiverId' : trans.ediTransaction.senderId }))|split('+', 4)
                                %}

                                <td style="width: 10%;">{{ result[0] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 40%;">{{ result[3] }}<br><br>
                                    {% if trans.errorCodeId == 2 %}
                                        <span style="background-color: yellow;">Accepted but <br/>errors were <br/>noted</span><br/>
                                    {% elseif trans.errorCodeId == 3 %}
                                        <span style="background-color: yellow;">Partially<br/> Accepted</span><br/><br/>
                                            {{ trans.acceptedTrans }} Accepted,<br/>
                                            {{ trans.noOfTrans - trans.acceptedTrans }} Rejected
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span style="background-color: yellow;">Rejected</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <br/>

                                    {% 
                                        set error=render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getError', {'id': trans.edi997DetailId }))|split('+') 
                                    %}
                                    <span>
                                        <p style="white-space: normal;">
                                            {% if error[0] != "0" %}
                                                {{ error[0] }}{{ "%02d"|format(error[1]) }}<br/>
                                                {{ error[2] }}
                                            {% else %}
                                                Errors were not specified in 997 file
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </p>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 10%;">{{ result[2] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 7%;">{{ result[1] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 5%;">{{ trans.noOfTrans }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 7%;">{{ trans.ediTransaction.receiverId }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 8%;">{{ trans.ediTransaction.senderId }}</td>
                                <td>
                                  <a href="" data-href="{{ path('matrix_edi_deleteFile', { 'id':trans.ediTransaction.ediTransactionId,'filename': trans.ediTransaction.fileName, 'url': 'matrix_edi_rejectedOutboundTrans' }) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><center><i class="fa fa-trash o" style="color:#1975A3;"></i></center></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="15" class="alignment result"> No Result Found </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Show us some code, where the error is throwed?

Comment: i added the repository

Comment: The error show you call an undefined method in the template `MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:rejectedTrans.html.twig` can you show us this code?

Comment: @olibiaz i added the snippet of the twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error.

In your Edi997SegmentInError entity object, there is no ediTransaction method.

Probable causes:

1. The method doesn't exist in any object
2. The method exists in an
       object, just not the one you're accessing

Looking at your repository method, that seems to be in your Edi997Details entity.

Presumably you'd access it via `{{trans.edi997Details.ediTransaction.receiverId}}` - but I'm really guessing there - you have to follow your object hierarchy correctly in twig. If you're not sure exactly which object you're accessing, try using `{{dump(trans)}}` to see what you have.

Comment: as you said i'd access it via {{trans.edi997Details.ediTransaction}}, is it possible because edi997Detials and ediTransaction are two different tables? will it not conflict, like  ' {{trans.edi997Details.ediTransaction.filename}} '

Comment: It really depends on how the doctrine relationships are set up between the entities, but it should work OK - or something very similar at least.

Comment: I've got another problem , how will i access acceptedTrans and it's under edi997Details? Is it trans.edi997Details.acceptedTrans?